# Sockets in C++: Connection Refused (macOS)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I have an odd issue. I have been attempting to learn to use network sockets in C/C++, and I'm currently having trouble understanding why my server code does not work. I have followed a tutorial's code almost to a T, and although the example code functions fine, my code does not. I can `telnet localhost 5000` to the example program just fine, but `telnet` simply gives me `connection refused` when I test my server code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declare int socket descriptor and call socket() to assign to it
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
        perror("Error on socket creation.");

    // declare address struct
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof serv_addr);

    // set values in address struct
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    // need to cast sockaddr_in to sockaddr struct
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr);

    // listen on socket with num of allowed connections
    if (listen(sockfd, 10) == -1)
        perror("Error on listen");

    int connfd;
    char msg [1025];
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof msg);

    while (1)
    {
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        strcpy(msg, "Message lol");
        write(connfd, msg, strlen(msg));
        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

This is example that functions as expected: https://pastebin.com/CG9ZWz49

And this is the tutorial I got the example from: 
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/586000/networking-and-socket-programming-tutorial-in-c

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will probably have bette lock if you tag it with the specific socket technology you are using. The code you wrote (and I am guessing) is specific to *nix and BSD sockets. C++ doesn't have any standard network programming API as part of its library.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code allows connection to port 5000.

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with this code is the lack of error handling on `bind()` and `accept()`

Comment: You haven't called receive on the accepted socket or saved it off in any fashion. Typically you accept a socket on one thread, save it off somewhere, and then call receive/andor send on it in another thread. You loop these threads until some shutdown signal occurs. You might want to get the threading model, use of condition variables, startup, shutdown stuff worked out in skeleton code before you tackle the more difficult topic of sockets.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: calling `receive()` is optional.  Clearly this code is a write-only server, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz what are you talking about???

Comment: He closes the socket immediatly. If he is expecting to receive data, it isn't going to happen.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz what makes you think OP expects data?

Comment: Run a netcat based server lintening on the same port and try to connect. If you can't, you have a networking problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: The fact that he wants to learn sockets makes me think he expects to call receive. The fact that he is learning C++ makes me think he doesn't want to sit in a while(true) loop, or call sleep....

Comment: You certainly make a lot of assumptions on unclear basis.

Comment: Yea, it comes from working with network programmers for the last 10 years who think while(1) is a cool thing to do....Ranks up there with catch(...){}

Comment: And it is related to the original question because... (please kindly complete this sentence)

Comment: To the OP. Also, if you haven't checked out boost::asio yet, it is a a more modern, and usually more efficient way to do sockets then BSD sockets on Windows or Linux. It wraps the operating system specific stuff for you. Windows uses IOCP which is way way faster. Messing with file descriptors is very 1990.

Comment: Sergey, if you'd like to argue for another 1000 comments, feel free to IM and we can argue all weekend while I wait for my play by email games to come in with their turns.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz A server that just writes to the socket without reading is perfectly valid. Consider the standard TIME server -- you connect to it, it sends the current time, and closes the connection.

Comment: @Barmar I never said it wasn't. I did say that while(1) is a problem. I also said, sleep is a bad idea. I also pointed out alot of things he can expect to do in the future. I never wrote an ANSWER. I made comments. I know some people like to think comments are answers, but they are comments.

Comment: Try adding error checking on the `bind()` call. I'll bet it's getting an error complaining that the address is unavailable, probably because you don't use the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Exactly none of the numerous things you have suggested will cause a connection refusal. Please stick to the point.

Comment: @EJP No one said they would. That's why they aren't in an answer. They are in comments. Comments are for commenting. Answers are for answering...